# Should I use ruby 1.9.2 when starting a new Rails 3.0 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

- App will run on Heroku

Dependencies include

- paperclip
- haml
- compass
- devise
- aws-s3

Reasons for or against? Any recommendation on another version of ruby?

**Update**
Heroku currently doesn't support 1.9.2 but it's expected to very soon based on [this post](http://twitter.com/heroku/status/21517412884). Rails 3.0 officially supports 1.9.2 (but not 1.9.1), so I decided to go ahead and use it.

**Update**
Heroku supports 1.9.2 on its beta stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say yes. By the time you're ready to roll your app (2-3 months?), more and more compatibility issues should be worked out. Also, if you run into any issues, you can submit patches and contribute to faster 1.9.2 compatibilities! ;)

But to answer your questions, given the gems you want to use, 1.9.2 is good. Heroku hasn't rolled out 1.9.2 yet though.

Comment: Yeah, it would be a few months, although I would like to run it on Heroku well before then. I see they support 1.9.1 currently, so I'm considering developing on that until they release 1.9.2.

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes, but take a look at this site before you do:

http://railsplugins.org/

It lists rails 3 compatibility  for gems/plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard ruby 1.9.2 is [faster](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-1-9-2-released-3700.html) than ruby 1.9.1. Your mileage may vary though.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the benchmarks. That's why I'm wanting to use 1.9.2 :)

Comment: @Trevor: I haven't. Where are they?

Comment: Hrm, seem to remember seeing them in a blog a while back. Google's not helping me out. You could always run your own :)